# Azure DevOps - Update user profile via Api

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to **perform a bulk update on a bunch of user profiles** (displayName, mail, etc.) without having the users credentials instead with the highest privileges in Azure Active Directory and DevOps via the Azure DevOps REST API. As the DevOps stays not in sync with the AAD.

It looks like the Update method of a user can only [*map* users to a new identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

This is what I have tried so far:

```cs
private Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchVstsUser(vssps.dev.azure.com.VstsUser user)
{

    var patchUser = new
    {
        displayName = user.Name,
        mailAddress = user.Mail,
        originId = user.AadId
    };

    return _devOpsGraphApi.PatchAsync($"users/{user.GraphDescriptor}?api-version=5.1-preview.1", patchUser);
 }
```

The API response with a 200 repsonse code but the acutal display name is not updated.

How can I update e. g. the display name of a user using the Azure DevOps Rest API?

Comment: It does not look like this API can achieve what you are looking for as far as I can see.

Comment: update: I checked again and found something, search for `
vso.identity_manage` on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) page. hope it may help you.

Comment: Thank you, but i have already looked into that. And as far as i can see i can only perfom api calls for the current user. I want to perform **bulk actions** (I didn't point that out in my question) without having access to the users credentials, but using the highest privileges in AAD and DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

From network tab i was able to get the api fro updating user in Azure devops.

[image]

Here is the request :

```
Request URL: https://####.###.azure.com/_apis/User/User
Request Method: PATCH
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: ##.###.#.###:###
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Similarly you can get it for your organization.

**Please note that its not a recommended way to updated the user. Assuming your azure devops account is tagged to Azure Active directory, so you should be able to user graph API to updated user profile using below url.**

```
PATCH /users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. But the first part is the same problem as above, which if forgot to point out in my question, i want to perform **bulk actions** without having the users credentials.

The problem with the seccond part is, which i want to address, is that the DevOps stays not in sync with the Active Directory.

Comment: I dont think any public API available to updated azure devops profile as it is expected to flow from  Azure AD.